# purpose of aria-valuemin/ aria-valuemax in bootstrap progress alternatives

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress-alternatives

In the above bootstrap example i see two attributes `aria-valuemin` and `aria-valuemx`. What are the purpose of those as there is already `aria-valuenow`?

I changed values of `aria-valuemx` and `aria-valuemin` but no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Attributes with `aira-*` is there for assistive technologies like screen reader.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA

https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-use-of-including-aria-label-or-aria-hidden-in-bootstrap-code-What-does-aria-refer-to